# Delimiter pattern that ignores anything but letters and numbers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have looked everywhere on Google and this website for a delimiter pattern that ignores punctuations (,./?><;:'"[{]}-_=+()*&^%$#@!) and only accepts numbers and words.

I have tried using:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt")).useDelimiter("[.,:;()?!\" \t]+~\\s");
```

and

```
      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("File.txt")).useDelimiter("[ ,!?.]+");
```

but the first one gives me a NoSuchElementException and the second one doesn't give me the result I need. What should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative class regex like:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
```

Btw, you have to escape `\` in java strings. For your delimiter:

```
"[.,:;()?!\" \t]+~\\s"  change it to:
"[.,:;()?!\" \\t]+~\\s"
```

Comment: @Fede hahahah my bad man, did notice you were the one who answered. At least he remembered :)

Comment: How do I make this delimiter also ignore white spaces? @Fede

Comment: @juliodesa just add the characters you want to ignore inside the character class `[^A-Za-z0-9]`. You could use `\s` for whitespaces like `[^A-Za-z0-9\s]`

Comment: @Fede that gives me an "illegal escape character" error :( sorry to be annoying, but this is adding an empty space into my ArrayList

Comment: @juliodesa you are using java, don't forget to escape the backslash, you have to use `\\s`

Answer (score 0):

If we want regex to work with characters other than ASCII, we should use Java character classes, like this

```
[^\\p{javaDigit}\\p{javaLetter}]
```

or Unicode characters classes, see Pattern API